# Linearization of a function using sqrt ln, confused with the denominator

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

[image]

Can someone please explain why the answer to this question is $\frac{9}{7\cdot169}$ rather than $\frac{9}{7\cdot\sqrt[]{169}}$?

I understand this may seem simple, but the concept is not at all sinking into my head.

thank you for the help!!

ANYBODY!?!?!?!?!?!

Answer (score 0):

We shall proceed with the very definition o the directional derivative, that is the change in the value of the function by a small change in the direction of the vector, divided by the norm of the vector. As such, we have:$$\begin{array}{c}f(x,y,z) = \ln \sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2} + {z^2}} \\{\rm{Answer}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f(3 + 3h,4 + 6h,12 - 2h) - f(3,4,12)}}{{\sqrt {{{\left( {3h} \right)}^2} + {{\left( {6h} \right)}^2} + {{\left( { - 2h} \right)}^2}} }}\\ = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{\ln \sqrt {{{\left( {3 + 3h} \right)}^2} + {{\left( {4 + 6h} \right)}^2} + {{\left( {12 - 2h} \right)}^2}}  - \ln \sqrt {{3^2} + {4^2} + {{12}^2}} }}{{7h}}\\ = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{\ln \left( {\frac{{169 + 18h}}{{169}}} \right)}}{{14h}}\\ = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{\ln \left( {1 + \frac{{18h}}{{169}}} \right)}}{{14h}}\\ = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{{14h}}\frac{{18h}}{{169}} = \frac{9}{{1183}}\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfKttLearuqr1ngBPrgarmqr1ngBPrgitL
% xBI9gBamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2D
% aeHbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaebbfv3ySLgzGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9
% irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-J
% frVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabi
% GaciaacaqabeaadaabauaaaOabaqqabaGaemOzayMaeiikaGIaemiE
% aGNaeiilaWIaemyEaKNaeiilaWIaemOEaONaeiykaKIaeyypa0Jagi
% iBaWMaeiOBa42aaOaaaeaacqWG4baEdaahaaWcbeqaaiabikdaYaaa
% kiabgUcaRiabdMha5naaCaaaleqabaGaeGOmaidaaOGaey4kaSIaem
% OEaO3aaWbaaSqabeaacqaIYaGmaaaabeaaaOqaaiabbgeabjabb6ga
% UjabbohaZjabbEha3jabbwgaLjabbkhaYjabg2da9maaxababaGagi
% iBaWMaeiyAaKMaeiyBa0galeaacqWGObaAcqGHsgIRcqaIWaamaeqa
% aOWaaSaaaeaacqWGMbGzcqGGOaakcqaIZaWmcqGHRaWkcqaIZaWmcq
% WGObaAcqGGSaalcqaI0aancqGHRaWkcqaI2aGncqWGObaAcqGGSaal
% cqaIXaqmcqaIYaGmcqGHsislcqaIYaGmcqWGObaAcqGGPaqkcqGHsi
% slcqWGMbGzcqGGOaakcqaIZaWmcqGGSaalcqaI0aancqGGSaalcqaI
% XaqmcqaIYaGmcqGGPaqkaeaadaGcaaqaamaabmaabaGaeG4mamJaem
% iAaGgacaGLOaGaayzkaaWaaWbaaSqabeaacqaIYaGmaaGccqGHRaWk
% daqadaqaaiabiAda2iabdIgaObGaayjkaiaawMcaamaaCaaaleqaba
% GaeGOmaidaaOGaey4kaSYaaeWaaeaacqGHsislcqaIYaGmcqWGObaA
% aiaawIcacaGLPaaadaahaaWcbeqaaiabikdaYaaaaeqaaaaaaOqaai
% abg2da9maaxababaGagiiBaWMaeiyAaKMaeiyBa0galeaacqWGObaA
% cqGHsgIRcqaIWaamaeqaaOWaaSaaaeaacyGGSbaBcqGGUbGBdaGcaa
% qaamaabmaabaGaeG4mamJaey4kaSIaeG4mamJaemiAaGgacaGLOaGa
% ayzkaaWaaWbaaSqabeaacqaIYaGmaaGccqGHRaWkdaqadaqaaiabis
% da0iabgUcaRiabiAda2iabdIgaObGaayjkaiaawMcaamaaCaaaleqa
% baGaeGOmaidaaOGaey4kaSYaaeWaaeaacqaIXaqmcqaIYaGmcqGHsi
% slcqaIYaGmcqWGObaAaiaawIcacaGLPaaadaahaaWcbeqaaiabikda
% YaaaaeqaaOGaeyOeI0IagiiBaWMaeiOBa42aaOaaaeaacqaIZaWmda
% ahaaWcbeqaaiabikdaYaaakiabgUcaRiabisda0maaCaaaleqabaGa
% eGOmaidaaOGaey4kaSIaeGymaeJaeGOmaiZaaWbaaSqabeaacqaIYa
% GmaaaabeaaaOqaaiabiEda3iabdIgaObaaaeaacqGH9aqpdaWfqaqa
% aiGbcYgaSjabcMgaPjabc2gaTbWcbaGaemiAaGMaeyOKH4QaeGimaa
% dabeaakmaalaaabaGagiiBaWMaeiOBa42aaeWaaeaadaWcaaqaaiab
% igdaXiabiAda2iabiMda5iabgUcaRiabigdaXiabiIda4iabdIgaOb
% qaaiabigdaXiabiAda2iabiMda5aaaaiaawIcacaGLPaaaaeaacqaI
% XaqmcqaI0aancqWGObaAaaaabaGaeyypa0ZaaCbeaeaacyGGSbaBcq
% GGPbqAcqGGTbqBaSqaaiabdIgaOjabgkziUkabicdaWaqabaGcdaWc
% aaqaaiGbcYgaSjabc6gaUnaabmaabaGaeGymaeJaey4kaSYaaSaaae
% aacqaIXaqmcqaI4aaocqWGObaAaeaacqaIXaqmcqaI2aGncqaI5aqo
% aaaacaGLOaGaayzkaaaabaGaeGymaeJaeGinaqJaemiAaGgaaaqaai
% abg2da9maaxababaGagiiBaWMaeiyAaKMaeiyBa0galeaacqWGObaA
% cqGHsgIRcqaIWaamaeqaaOWaaSaaaeaacqaIXaqmaeaacqaIXaqmcq
% aI0aancqWGObaAaaWaaSaaaeaacqaIXaqmcqaI4aaocqWGObaAaeaa
% cqaIXaqmcqaI2aGncqaI5aqoaaGaeyypa0ZaaSaaaeaacqaI5aqoae
% aacqaIXaqmcqaIXaqmcqaI4aaocqaIZaWmaaaaaaa!1672!
$$